# How to setup event tracking on Google Analytics on form submission?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-analytics

Im trying to track when a user hits the submit button on a contact form.
The page's URL doesn't change, its static.
I can't track a differnt URL after submission, the only option would be to track when a user hits the submit button.

*Do I need to edit my analytics account?

Where do I add the additional javascript?

UA is installed correctly (analytics.js)

I'm new to GA and javascript so please break it down for me.*

Thanks

Comment: It's in the manual: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I can't track a differnt URL after submission, the only option would be to track when a user hits the submit button.
```

That is a bit of a non sequitur. Even when the Url does not change there is probably some stuff happening - before you send it there is probably some form validation, and there is some action behind the scene to send there form, like e.g an ajax call.

You could attach event tracking to a submit handler:

```
<form onSubmit="ga('send','event','category','action','label')">
<input type="text" id="text" name="text">
<input type="submit">
 </form>
```

However this would just tell you that somebody hit the submit button, not if they filled in the form correctly or if the form actually has been sent.

Now I enter speculation land, because I do not know how your form actually works - maybe you can show us an url or give more information.

But maybe  you have a validation function that is called on the submit action of the form to see if the form is filled in correctly. In that case it would be advisable to do the tracking in the validation function (horribly simplified example, not production code):

```
<form onSubmit="validate()"><input type="text" id="text" name="text"><input type="submit"></form>

<script>
function validate() {
 var test = document.querySelector('#text').value
 if(test = "") {
    ga('send','event','Form','Submit','Submitted, but not filled in');
    return false;
 }
 ga('send','event','Form','Submit','Submitted with correct values');
 return true;
}
</script>
```

That's a tad better, at least it tracks the difference between correct submissions and invalid submissions.

Even more speculation: If your form is sent without page reloads it uses probably an ajax call, and there is a huge probability that is uses [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) (I say that because a) it really is probable and b) it's easier to construct an example in jQuery.  The same can be achivied with other libraries or in native JS, but the example will produce an error if you do not use jQuery).

jQuery has a thing called "global ajax handlers". "Global" means they are not callbacks for a specific action, they hook into jQuerys ajax "mechanism" whenever a call to an ajax function is made. The following might work if you have only one aja event per page (else you need logic to distinguish the different ajax event e.g, by checking the url they are being send to), and allows you to track if the ajax call has returned successfully, like when your form data has been send to the server and the request return a 2xx status code:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
 ga('send','event','Form','Submit','Yeah, form data sent to the server');
});
```

However this does not tell you if the data has been processed correctly. For that you need to make the server emit  a success message and check the response:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url == "formprocessor.php" ) {

      if(xhr.responseText.indexOf("success") > -1) {
       ga('send','event','Form','Response Received','Form data processed ');
      } else {
       ga('send','event','Form','Response Received','Form data NOT processed ');
      }
  }
});
```

The global ajax event handler is attached to the document - you  can put that anywhere on your page, it will do nothing unless an ajax event was called.

Again, **this is not production code. Do not try to copy and paste.**

This was certainly a bit much if you are new to this, but it should at least help you to improve the question and to see what kind of things are possible. If you can share an Url to your form I can possibly improve the answer.

Comment: Thank you!, this is exactly what I wanted to know, I'm also running two GA roperty instances, would the data from the onSubmit script send data to both properties?

Comment: No. You would need to create named trackers (there are already a few posts on named trackers on stackoverflow) and send the calls to both tracker instances.

Comment: @RzK, an alternative to using named dual trackers would be to use a GA plugin that send the data to multiple accounts, the advantage being that you'd need to do your tracking calls only once and the plugins takes care that calls go to two accounts.  E.g. David Vallejo hast started a small project on his blog, maybe you want to help out (at least with suggestions): https://www.thyngster.com/universal-analytics-plugin-dual-tracking/.